# Требуется регулярное выражение, заменяющее все знаки кроме первого минуса и чисел на ""

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```js
     const text = "a-a1s2d3f-4g5h-6i-j-7k8l9";
     const result = text.replace(/[^-\d]+/g, "");

     console.log(result);
```

Моя регулярка выводит -123-45-6--789
Должно получиться: -123456789
Пробовал разные, не могу подобрать

Comment: возможно после этого надо прогнать еще через одну регулярку

Comment: хотя минуса в начале может и не быть, тогда должно вернуться просто 123456789

Comment: @Andrew если минус не нужен text.replace(/\D/gi, "")

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew идеально работает, спасибо большое!

Comment: Я "перенёс" комментарий в ответ.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew а как добавить знак точку, если она находится между числами. из "a-a1s2d3.f-4g5h-6i-j-7k8l9"  (точка после 3), получить -123.456789

Comment: @Andrew попробуйте `\D` замените на `[^\d.]`

Comment: @ipatev_nn оставляет точку в любом месте, нужно именно условие, что она находится между числами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```js
const text = "a-1s2d3f-4g5h-6i-j-7k8l9";
const result = text.replace(/^[^\d-]*(-)|\D/g, "$1");
console.log(result);
```

См. [пример использования регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/0Yq4Jz/3).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[^\d-]*` - ноль и более символов, отличных от цифр и `-`
- `(-)` - Подмаска №1: `-` (`$1` в шаблоне замены восстанавливает дефис, если он был найден в оригинальной строке)
- `|` - или
- `\D` - символ, отличный от цифры.

Comment: От меня тоже спасибо. Слежу за Вами потихоньку :)

Comment: как в эту регулярку добавить проверку на знак "." между двумя числами

Comment: @Andrew Честно говоря, лучше добавить ещё один `replace`. Однако я не знаю, какую точку вы хотите оставить, первую или последнюю, и какую точку считать первой, та, что перед первой цифрой, или после первой цифры...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew та, перед которой есть какое-либо число, не зависимо что за знаки между ними, и так же если после нее есть число

Comment: грубо говоря, чтобы из такой каши "a-a1s2d3.f-4g5h-6i-j-7k8l9" получилось отрицательное дробное

Comment: @Andrew `text.replace(/^[^\d-]*(-)|[^\d.]/g, "$1").replace(/^(-?\d+\.\d)|\./g, '$1')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew у меня есть моя регулярка, которая тестит, что точка находится между числами /^\d+(\.\d*)?$/

Comment: @Andrew Хорошая регулярка, только тут не поможет.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ваша не работает(

Comment: @Andrew Это если точки в начале были? Тогда `text.replace(/^[^\d-]*(-)|[^\d.]/g, "$1").replace(/^(.*?\d+)\.+(?=\d)|\./g, (_, x) => x ? x.replace(/\./g, '') + "." : "")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew если потестить на такой строке "a-.a1.s2d3.f-4g5h-6i-j-7k8l9" (где до точки нет чисел. тут надо оставить любую одну между числами). Пойму, если не ответите, в любом случае большое спасибо)

Comment: Вопрос закрыт в полном объеме) спасибо огромное

Comment: Или `text.replace(/^[^\d-]*(-)|[^\d.]/g, "$1").replace(/^\.*(-?)\.*(\d+)(\.)+(?=\d)|\./g, "$1$2$3")` - но это надо ещё протестировать.